# Wish to initialize member before passing to parent constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

Here is a toy example of my conundrum:

```
public abstract class Car {
    public Car(Seat[] seatsParam) {    // Could be protected.
        driverSeat = new DriverSeat();
        seats = new ArrayList<Seat>();
        seats.add(driverSeat);
        seats.addAll(seatsParam);
    }
    private final List<Seat> seats;
    private final DriverSeat driverSeat;
}

public class MyCar extends Car {
    public MyCar() {
        super(new Seat[]{new PassengerSeat()});    // Cannot assign to member.
    }
    public PassengerSeat getPassengerSeat() {  // Would like this accessor.
        return passengerSeat;
    }
    private final PassengerSeat passengerSeat;
}
```

Car has a list of Seat (the seat supertype), ideally initialized in the constructor.  Every car has a DriverSeat.  MyCar also has a PassengerSeat which I would like to access from the subtype, but also from the parent list (as a Seat).

Some things that I have shot down:

- The code above: passengerSeat won't be initialized in the subclass.  I could get the list in MyCar's constructor and downcast, but this is ugly.
- Making passengerSeat static: it *shouldn't* be static since there could be many other MyCars with unique seats.
- Have Car define an abstract getSubclassSeats() to which it adds driverSeat: this won't work in the constructor since passengerSeat won't have been initialized.  I could make seats non-final and do it after the constructor but, again, ugly.

I want to say this is something I should be able to express in OO, define a variable and pass it to the parent to reference.  But I cannot think of how to do it nicely.  It's been awhile since I worked with C++, but is this what initialization lists solve?  If so, does Java have an equivalent?

Comment: I guess another strategy is to have everything in Car that operates on seats do driverSeat and then getChildSeats() separately.  Again, works but is not elegant.

Comment: Tryy passing in `new Seat[] { new PassengerSeat() }` instead. You are not properly passing an array

Comment: Oh thanks, I've updated it.  But my problem isn't compilation but rather the fact that the 'new PassengerSeat()' becomes lost to the subtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen people with similar problems use thread-local variables and god knows what other awful tricks, luckily there's an easy solution:

```
public MyCar() {
    this(new PassengerSeat());   
}

private MyCar(PassengerSeat seat) {
    super(new PassengerSeat[]{seat});   
    // Well do something with your seat now.
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I always thought of constructors as only calling up the inheritance chain.

Comment: @mr_dude Delegating constructors as they are called are new with C++11 -  not that surprising you hadn't heard of them.